# Why it's not playing all the sentences and each sentence in a line?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class Dialog : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI textDisplay;
    public string[] sentences;
    public float typingSpeed;

    private int index= 0;

    IEnumerator Type()
    {
        foreach(char letter in sentences[index].ToCharArray())
        {
            textDisplay.text += letter;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(typingSpeed);
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Type());
    }
}
```

I have 2 sentences. For example the first sentence is :

Hello world Hi everyone

And the second sentence is :

My name is Daniel who are you ?

When I play the game it's playing only the first sentence and also breaking it.
It's playing it like this :

Hello
world
Hi
everyone

Instead it should play all the sentences like this :

Hello world Hi everyone

Then the next sentence at the same place of the firsto ne :

My name is Daniel who are you ?

Comment: When did you plan to increment your index?

Answer (score 0):

Your index variable is being used to index into the sentence array by the first sentence only.

If you want to go through all of the sentences you could wrap your sentences in another loop that indexes through the sentences array when you're finished presenting it. You may also want to wait for some period and clear your textDisplay.text value at the start or end of the outer loop.

Comment: This answer would be even better if it showed an example of how to do that — it looks like OP might not be experienced with nested loops, so a code snippet might help.

Answer (score 0):

you are just lopping the through characters in first sentence as the index never gets updated. just wrap your code with new for or foreach loop. this is just my psudo code for your problem.

```
string[] sentences;
float TypeSpeed;
ienumerator displayText()
{
 for(int i=0; i<sentences.length;i++)
 {
   for(int j=0;j<sentences[i].length;j++)
   {
    displayText+= sentences[i][j];
    yield return new waitForSeconds(speed);
   }
 }
}
```

its just a psudo code. check your errors in code editor